# Points in R with Bold + Symbol

Tags: r, symbols, points

I need to make those "+" in bold. Is it possible or should I used other symbols?

```
 plot(1:10,1:10,type="l")
 points(1:10,rep(5,10),pch="+")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try with `pch=3` and `lwd`

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type="l")
points(1:10,rep(5,10),pch=3,lwd=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `text` with `font=2`:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type="l")
text(1:10,rep(5,10),label="+",font=2)
```

[image]